# List column(Text) not saving/showing data after setting attribute multiple=true on Attachments control so to enable uploading multiple Files at a time

Tags: list, sharepoint, attachment, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

By default we can only upload one file at a time so I followed solution given here(`https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/attach-multiple-files-to-sharepoint-list-item-with-default-attachment-of-new-for/`). Now I am unable to store **RFI No** column(text). It *maybe* stores value on form submit but the value does not show. Following is my column setting:

[image]

List view and inspect element:

[image]
[image]

I simply added the code in **NewForm.aspx** which works and enables user to upload multiple files but now New Item form does not save **RFI No** value which is not in anyway dependent on **Attachments** field

[image]

If I log the value of **RFI No** column to workflow history list through Workflow it is showing the saved value there..

Answer (score 0):

If so, the value is saved in the **RFI No** column. Looks like there are some code in the list view page which hided the column value, that's why  the value does not show.

You could click Edit page in the site settings to check if there are script editor or content editor web partin the view page.